# PHP array merge?

Tags: php

I have

```
Array_A ( [0] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-28 , [totalCount] => )
          [1] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-29 , [totalCount] => )
          [2] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-30 , [totalCount] => ) )

Array_B ( [10] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-28 , [totalCount] => 30 )
          [11] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-30 , [totalCount] => 40 )
          [12] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-12-05 , [totalCount] => 50 ) )
```

How to I do if I need to replace the Array_A with the values from the Array_B and the output should be

```
Array_A ( [0] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-28 , [totalCount] => 30 )
          [1] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-29 , [totalCount] =>    )
          [2] => Array ( [DATE] => 2012-11-30 , [totalCount] => 40 ) )
```

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: This problem is very specific, you will not likely find a built-in API for this, you will have to write your own loop.

Comment: I have read the doc from php and tried standard function but none is desired

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just noticed the part where you only want the keys from `array_a` to be used, this loop wil do.

```
foreach($array_a as $key => $value){
    if (array_key_exists($key, $array_b){
        $result[$key] = $array_b[$key]; 
    } else {
        $result[$key] = null;
    }
}
```

Or, if you want the value of `array_a` being used if the key in `array_b` does not exist, simply replace the statement in the `else`-clause to: `$result[$key] = $value;`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$result = array_merge_recursive($Array_A, $Array_B);
print_r($result);
```